# Reboot script for ubunut on system hang

Tags: linux, script, freeze, ubuntu-16.04

I have created a Qt app for Ubuntu 16.04 which will run every time when system is on. But sometimes I have seen that the system is getting frozen or hang when the application is running for long time. I have tested the application for memory leak but there is no memory leak I found, also the RAM and CPU usage is 70-80 percent most of the time. The system run fine for 24 days sometimes but  I have seen some random freeze happen some days.

So I have implemented background monitoring script which will monitor the system and application.  Right now I have implemented the RAM and CPU usage monitoring and if it exceed a threshold the script will restart the Application. Similarly is there any way to detect the system freeze or hang so I can issue reboot command inside the script.

Comment: If the system hangs or freezes, there is no way that anything could reboot the system, besides physically pressing the reboot button..

Comment: So is there any way to identify that system is going to freeze.

Comment: And how  remote servers normally handle such a situation.

Comment: You mean if the graphics / display / mouse processes stop responding?

Comment: Yes, any kind of freeze like graphics / display / mouse